# How to fix the threads on a bolt?

Tags: thread

I have a bolt and nut set which is used to remove suspension bushings. I put a lot of torque on the nut and the bolt is slightly bent. There is also a slight deformation on the threads, and the nut is getting caught on it and I can't screw it any further. I have tried another nut and in reverse direction and it always gets stuck at the same place.

How can I fix the threads on the bolt?

[image]

Comment: They make thread chasers that do not remove material, they push the threads back into proper position. This is what I would use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the bolt, as any die used to chase the threads will weaken or reduce them further.

When replacing find a bolt of a larger diameter if possible and a coarser thread which will be stronger. Also find a bolt that is hardened as that will also be stronger.

Comment: It's a 500mm bolt and I don't need to apply force at the area I need to fix. I just need to fix it so I can screw the nut past that point and use a different position on the bolt. Would a die or a file work better?

Comment: I would use the die but if you don’t have one and need to use it then you can make do with a file. Just do the minimum though.

Comment: @tgun926 - If the bolt is stretched, no amount of filing or using a die will fix the issue because the threads will be elongated at the point of damage. The only way a file would fix it would be to completely remove the threads at the point of damage ... that's not really fixing it, it would just allow you to slide the nut past the damaged area.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I think you're correct. A thread file did absolutely nothing, and the threads all look in tact. So they must be stretched.

Answer (score 0):

get you a Tap and Die Set they work great